# ID of the selected users

Tags: android, facebook

I'm following the guide Facebook for Developers, and learning to use the Facebook SDK. Currently I am constructing my application for my Thesis in Computer Science to select and display my Facebook friends (just to Show Friends https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends # step 1).

Now I need to capture the user ID of the selected user and then perform a query to get the places I've been tagged by his friends, or which were checked-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to query the checkin table using FQL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin

try to specify the "author_uid" field (id of a friend) or your id is in "tagged_uids" field.

Just send a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=your_fql_query and the response will be json.

Comment: In the graph api use this for facebook places:  /me/friends?fields=id,name,checkins.fields(place,id),locations.fields(place,id)                                                         but I can not find a similar query in FQL.Currently I have done this:                                                     {'checkin': 'SELECT author_uid,coords,checkin_id,tagged_uids FROM checkin WHERE author_uid=524983333 OR tagged_uids=524983333  ',
'location_post':'SELECT coords FROM location_post WHERE author_uid=524983333 OR tagged_uids=524983333 '}                     What do you think?

Comment: For places that you were tagged by the selected user's friends: "SELECT coords FROM location_post WHERE tagged_uids=your_fb_id AND author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=selected_user_id)". Similar query for checkin (in fact i don't really know what is "checkin" :( )

Comment: I apologize for my English, I'm Italian and I hope to be able to express myself well. I want to find the places of my facebook friends, not the ones where I have been tagged, but their checkin and the places where they were tagged. In my application, I select one or more friends and I already know their id